# Cakephp Console output on a mac shows HTML

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I've started to experiment with Cakephp Console tasks, following the help/ advice to perform the following:

```
$ cd /path/to/cakephp/app
$ Console/cake
```

On my Mac, this seems to just output error HTML, rather than giving me output such as the below:

### Welcome to CakePHP v1.2.2.8120 Console

Edit. Running this instead:

```
$ cd /path/to/cakephp/lib/Console
$ ./cake
```

Works ok, but without picking up the Shell I've created inside my project.

Any obvious reasons on why this might be?

Comment: You should *not* go into Console to run it. It should work from outside, the app dir itself as you initially tried. Your version looks totally wrong, though (it can't be 1.2). So you are composer requiring CakePHP 2.7 as you should?

Comment: Sorry, the Welcome version is a red herring @mark - this was something I copied in from elsewhere. The problem was I hadn't set my bash path up properly to recognise the command from inside the app directory. The error was being caused by something else, and changing the debug level illustrated that in the console.